# Running Spark history server in Docker to view AWS Glue jobs

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

I have set up AWS Glue to output Spark event logs so that they can be imported into Spark History Server.  AWS provide a [CloudFormation stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-spark-ui-history.html) for this, I just want to run the history server locally and import the event logs.  I want to use Docker for this so colleagues can easily run the same thing.

I'm running into problems because the history server is a daemon process, so the container starts and immediately shuts down.

How can I keep the Docker image alive?

My Dockerfile is as follows

```
ARG SPARK_IMAGE=gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.4
FROM ${SPARK_IMAGE}

RUN apk --update add coreutils

RUN mkdir /tmp/spark-events

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/spark/sbin/start-history-server.sh"]
```

I start it using:

```
docker run -v ${PWD}/events:/tmp/spark-events -p 18080:18080 sparkhistoryserver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the SPARK_NO_DAEMONIZE environment variable, see [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/41be5125a1581a1c1dd611a98e823f356419f137/sbin/spark-daemon.sh#L30).  This will keep the container alive.

Just modify your Dockerfile as follows:

```
ARG SPARK_IMAGE=gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.4
FROM ${SPARK_IMAGE}

RUN apk --update add coreutils

RUN mkdir /tmp/spark-events

ENV SPARK_NO_DAEMONIZE TRUE
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/spark/sbin/start-history-server.sh"]
```

See [here](https://github.com/moj-analytical-services/docker_spark_history_ui) for a repo with more detailed readme.

Comment: for windows users I had to do something like this, with lower case c on the drive, bcz that caused an issue, and swap \ for /   `docker run -v c:/Users/ron/Documents/Glue/Spark-UI/events:/tmp/spark-events -p 18080:18080 sparkhistoryserver`